# do i need to install alamofire in code if share the code to other system

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I have installed alamofire using PODS on my macbook in my current project.
Now if i share same project to some other person, do he/she also need to install alamofire to run the project ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, They have to install pods. If the other user don't have cocoapods. They have to install cocoapods first.

1.First open your terminal

2.Then update your gem file with command

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

3.Then give your project path

cd /Path of project

```
pod install
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you going to share the project with the other person?

If you're using git the common approach is to have `Pods/` directory declared in `.gitignore` file. In such case the person needs to run `pod install` after fetching the project. This requires `Podfile` and `Podfile.lock` files to make sure that you both work on the same version of the library.

If you simply copy-paste the directory then it's not required at all, as all the files (including workspace and pods) are already attached.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they will have to install `alamofire`.

They will have to navigate to the project's root directory and then in their terminal run the following command `pod install`